# Variables in CSS - why can't they be used?

Tags: css, sass, less, w3c

It quite bothers me for a while and I can't find the answer anywhere: **WHY** doesn't pure CSS allow us to use variables?

We all know about SASS and LESS preprocessors that make our life so much easier - for instance just by letting us to use variables. Is there any particular reason why W3C hasn't implemented such feature in CSS itself yet?

I suppose all developers (also those from W3C) would agree that the it would be a great step forward. Are there any particular reasons why it hasn't been taken (yet)?

Comment: Now, there are variables in CSS

Comment: Probably because traditional variables (as you might understand them) don't fit into how CSS works? Even custom properties aka cascading vars, despite the name, aren't anywhere near the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To conclude my research:

You DON'T have to use SASS or LESS to take advantage of variables in CSS.

To set some reusable values in CSS you have to declare them using custom property notation, e.g. `--main-color: black;`

Then you can access them anywhere in your styles file using the var() function, e.g. `color: var(--main-color);`

Working example below:

```css
:root {
  --main-theme-color: red;
}

.one {
  background-color: var(--main-theme-color);
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.two {
  background-color: var(--main-theme-color);
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.three {
  background-color: var(--main-theme-color);
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.four {
  background-color: black;
  color: var(--main-theme-color);
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"> </div>
<div class="two"> </div>
<div class="three"> </div>
<div class="four"> RED </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

well there is a spec called custom properties 
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/

but support is a bit of an issue right now.. but it is there.. 
http://caniuse.com/css-variables/embed

you can/should start with css variables 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables